# Save the position (CGPoints) of a image

Tags: iphone, image, save, coordinates, cgpoint

I'm trying to save the positions of several images whom are inside my view. How can i store the coordinates of the images so that when the App launches the images are still at the same location?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the .frame.origin and save them somewhere

Comment: brings me the next question. What type of function is able to save this? NSUserDefaults?